# How do I do "shared" subscriptions in EMQTT 2.0.7?

Tags: mqtt

http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/getstarted.html - Features 'Shared Subscription'

According to the docs, it supports a feature for 'shared subscriptions'.  I have not found the docs or exampes that describe how to subscribe as 'shared'.  How is this done in EMQTT 2.0.7?

Answer (score 0):

http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/advanced.html#shared-subscription

If emq is clustered, use `$local/$share/` to make sure only one message processed. 
e.g.

```
[shell-1]$ mosquito_sub -t “$local/$share/gp/topic1”
[shell-2]$ mosquito_sub -t “$local/$share/gp/topic1”
[shell-3]$ mosquito_pub -t “$local/$share/gp/topic1” -m hello1
```